# UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) turns off (inactive) after a while

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, ufw

I'm a little lost and hope someone can point me into the right direction to solve my problem. I have a server running with a Debian distribution and I'm using UFW as firewall. The configuration and setup was pretty easy and I started the firewall as documented with:

```
manly@server:~$ sudo ufw enable
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
```

If I check, if ufw is running I receive (correctly):

```
manly@server:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

After some time (I check daily), the firewall turns inactive - even without any restart in between -, i.e., status returns inactive:

```
manly@server:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I have no idea why. What can I check to figure out the reasons behind that weird behavior. I'm thankful for any advice!

**Update:**

I noticed something, which may help to find a solution. So I start the ufw with the sudo ufw enable in an ssh session. It seems like, that if I keep the ssh session open, the firewall is enabled. If I close the ssh session (exit), the ufw status will be set to inactive after some time. Do I have to start the ufw in any special manner?

Comment: System logs and shell histories... http://serverfault.com/questions/516838/where-are-the-logs-for-ufw-located-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: @user356540 I checked the logs and the shell history. The logs just includes blocked requests like:
Aug  3 00:49:34 server kernel: [266192.716803] [UFW BLOCK] IN=... OUT= MAC=... SRC=... DST=... LEN=46 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=5813 PROTO=UDP SPT=38793 DPT=53413 LEN=26

Comment: I meant the firewall process log as opposed to the packet filtering log. Sorry for not being more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some digging and talking to the support, we finally figured out, what stops UFW. The system also had `APF` (Advanced Policy Firewall - R-fx Networks) configured, which adds a cron-job to the system. The job removes all rules on midnight and resets the rules defined for `APF`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your configuration file `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` as root and set `ENABLED=yes`:

```
# /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
#

# Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
# to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
ENABLED=yes

# Please use the 'ufw' command to set the loglevel. Eg: 'ufw logging medium'.
# See 'man ufw' for details.
LOGLEVEL=low
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The file already has the enabled set to yes. I added some further information to the case, which may help to find a solution (ssh session?)